# Meaning of 'imposta di registro'

Tags: translation, meaning

The meaning of this term remains obscure to me. Intuitively I choose between

- a registration fee;
- a standard payment;
- a fixed tax payment

and those meanings given by the [linguee.it](http://www.linguee.it/italiano-inglese/search?source=auto&query=imposta%20di%20registro%20):

- a registration charge;
- a registration duty.

Sometimes the term seems having a broad meaning, while at the other moments it is likely being specific.

So, is it a variable amount or is it a fixed payment? Is it applied under different cirumstances or under the same ones?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very technical question. You need to understand some Italian to read its definition. Anyway the tax is due when you want or have  to register a document to make it official. Circumstances may vary according to the nature of the document ( a private contract, a public contract, etc.). The amount may be fixed or vary according to the amount of the contract. It is a question of fiscal nature which cannot be summarised  in a few lines, but I hope this helps:

[Imposta di registro](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imposta_di_registro):

> - L'imposta di registro è un tributo previsto dall'ordinamento della Repubblica italiana dovuto per la registrazione di determinati atti giuridici presso l'Agenzia delle Entrate (prima dell'unificazione degli uffici fiscali la registrazione era effettuata presso l'Ufficio del Registro).
> - Si presenta come tributo avente natura di tassa, quando è correlata all'erogazione di un servizio da parte della pubblica amministrazione, di imposta quando è determinata in proporzione al valore economico dell'atto o del negozio.
> - Essa è regolata dal Testo unico dell'imposta di registro, approvato con D.P.R. 26 aprile 1986, n. 131.